# Many simple-class instances, is my practice the best solution?

Tags: java, performance, class, object, instance

I'm developing a game which uses Vector2 class to perform required calculations.
It's a simple class as you can imagine: fields "x", "y", some methods like add(), sub(), scl()

If I was creating methods like that:

```
public void doSomething() {
    Vector2 offset = new Vector2(10, 3);
    offset.rotate(45).add(3, 2);

    Vector2 position = new Vector2(20, 35);
    position.sub(4, 5).add(offset);

    // something else
}
```

There were created a lot of Vector2 class instances and the GC had a lot work to do, in one game step (1/40 of second) there was over 200 vectors created. Therefore, game FPS was dropping when GC ran.

I tried to use pools to recycle created instances, but it was terrible misstake, collecting and disposing them took more time than GC did.

So I thought to pre-create instances and use them like that:

```
private final Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(), v2 = new Vector2();
public void doSomething() {

    Vector2 offset = v1;
    offset.set(10, 3);
    offset.rotate(45).add(3, 2);

    Vector2 position = v2;
    position.set(20, 35);
    position.sub(4, 5).add(offset);

    // something else
}
```

v1 and v2 are class fields and they are instantiated once when object is created.
This way I achieved both performance and kept friendly names for my variables.

However, I'm wondering if it's good solution and be informed about potential risks of using it. Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: is the numbers are static ? (x,y is gonna change based on Game ? ). is the doSomething is threadsafe ?

Comment: They're not static. Game logic is single thread.

Comment: Well if they are instance objects that won't be concurrently modified then make them instance objects as you did. Once they are encapsulated, make sure not to let them escape and you should be ok.

Comment: @Adrian Adamczyk , i would go with Joop Eggen Approach. Since it is just two variables and single Thread game. All you need is static utility methods to get the vector ( x,y) and get x and y as his example and perform the activity

Answer (score 3):

As you experimented yourself a lot, what about radically moving away from objects?

Pack `(x, y)` as two shorts into an int, or as two ints into a long. Make an abstract class with static functions for operations.

```
public class Vector2 {
    private Vector2 {}

    public static short x(int v) {
        return (short)(v & 0xFFFF);
    }

    public static int add(int u, int v) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You have to be careful with overflow especially when using negative numbers. But it's surely doable.

Answer (score 2):

Potential risk is concurrent modification, either due to:

1) Your `doSomething` method being invoked by several threads at once (in the previous situation each invokation created its own local `Vector2` instances). Solution: add the synchronization needed. Even in a single-threaded scenario, document that there may be issues if the method as it is is called concurrently.

2) Even in a single-threaded situation, that you (or a fellow programmer) forget that the vector is intended to be "locally" used and modify it from another method. Solution: document it well.